# USing wxWidgets in Firebreath projects

Tags: xcode, macos, wxwidgets, xcode3.2, firebreath

Am using wxWidgets in FireBreath plugin project in xcode.

Have added

1. C++ flags(`-I/usr/lib/wx/include/mac-unicode-debug-2.8 -I/usr/include/wx-2.8 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGE_FILES -D__WXDEBUG__ -D__WXMAC__`)
2. other linker flags(`-framework IOKit -framework Carbon -framework Cocoa -framework System -framework QuickTime -framework OpenGL -framework AGL -lwx_macud-2.8`) in project settings.

but am getting following errors,...

```
wx/wx.h: No such file or directory
```

and build getting failed.

Can someone tell me wat I am missing??

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

You should not be adding things to the project directly using xcode; FireBreath projects use cmake to define the project and then are built into xcode (or whatever other kind) projects.

For information on how to add libraries with CMake and FireBreath: http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/Using+Libraries

Also on that page it talks about how to add include directories; apparently your manual modifications aren't working properly in that regard, but you need to add your /usr/include/wx-2.8 and possibly other related include directories in your CMakeLists.txt or Mac/projectDef.cmake (probably a better place for mac specific options) files.

To add the definitions, use add_definitions

All of these commands are documented here: http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake2.6docs.html

Note that after changing any cmake project files you need to rerun the prep script.  You do not *ever* need to rerun fbgen for a specific project -- that just creates the skeleton for you, nothing more.

Comment: ok... I have added include_directories(${/usr/include/wx-2.8/wx}) in  CMakeLists.txt file and I run the command prepmac.sh but still I am gettin the same error.. I am very new to all these stuff. can u please explain step by step please

Comment: while you _shouldn't_ directly tweak projects, I don't see it as a bad way to quickly try things out - if you're not expert with CMake this lets you figure out if a problem is due to not knowing CMake or something else. Obviously only a temporary thig though.

Comment: getting linker error lik these : please suggest
"wxThread::TestDestroy()", referenced from:
  "typeinfo for wxThread", referenced from:
  "wxRect2DInt::operator=(wxRect2DInt const&)", referenced from:
  "wxThread::~wxThread()", referenced from:

Comment: @soorajsubramanya you should probably be aware that if you want help in the future it would be a good idea to upvote helpful answers and mark an answer correct; people don't like to see "0% accepted rate" on your profile